# Method invocation failed while trying to create a pop up

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-core

```
$out = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface |
    select name , BytesTotalPersec

$out.popup("Network status",0,"Done",0x1)
```

> Error : Method invocation failed because
>   [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a
>   method named  'popup'. At line:2 char:1
>   + $out.popup("Network status",0,"Done",0x1)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (popup:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Like the error says, that object doesn't have a popup method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PopUp is a method called from the Wscript.Shell class.  It won't work from a WMI instance object (or collection of instances).  If you wanted to display the results of that WMI query using the pop-up style message box from your example you would have to do something like this.

```
$out = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | select name , BytesTotalPersec | Out-String

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Network Status:`n $out",0,"Done",0x1)
```

Or you can simplify it a bit by just piping the data to a gridview.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | select name , BytesTotalPersec | Out-GridView
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[messagebox]::show('hello world')
```